# Geometry/constructions

Tags: geometric-construction

I want to contruct a trapes and I am finding it hard to find the last point D.

1) Construct a segment AB = 6.8 cm
2) Construct an angle at 67,5 degrees at A. 
3) Construct AC = 8 cm 
4) CD is parallell to AB
**5) The distance between D and AB is equal to the distance between D and BC**

Problem: 5) 
Well, I need a referance point on the segments AB and BC, dont I?

Comment: Given two non-parallel lines, the locus of points that are equidistant to those lines is the angle bisector between those lines

Answer (score 0):

As you say the angle at A is angle CAB not angle DAB....  Then...

Point C Is known to us.

Draw a parallel through C which is parallel to AB.

Now bisect angle ABC. We do this because first the point D is equidistant from AB and BC...  So by locus theorem it will lie on bisector of AB and BC. And AB is parallel CD so D must also lie on parallel through C.

To bisect an angle, refer website

www.mathopenref.com/constbisectangle.html

The point where the parallel and bisector will meet is the point D.

Good day!

Comment: We know point C precisely, because AC = 8 and we know the angle A? Then we can draw the segment BC. So we can bisect the angle ABC?

Comment: Well first of all tell me is the shape name ABCD or ABDC?

Comment: ABCD, A left vertex, B right vertex, C right upper vertex and D, left upper vertex.

Comment: Okay the angle at A is the angle AC makes with AB then...

Comment: Then it's simple....  Just draw parallel through C which is parallel to AB and then bisect AB and BC.  The point where two lines will meet is point D

Comment: To bisect the angle refer www.mathopenref.com/constbisectangle.html

Comment: I thought the angle at A was the angle which AD made with AB